# Czech encoding trouble

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently made a script that that is simply adding things to database. However, the text inserted is in Czech. So far I've never made anything that wouldn't expect English input, so I'm sort of new to encoding.

The Czech language has these special characters: ěščřžýáíéúů. I'd say they all work except for: ř, ú, ů, č which just get converted to: �?. How would I fix this?

I'm currently doing `htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')` and then de-code it with `html_entity_decode($text)`.

The database is using `utf8_czech_ci` encoding.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: If I take out the whole htmlentities part, I get same result, but with: `?` instead of some characters.

Comment: Make sure you're really using [UTF-8 everywhere](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: Are you sure they are wrong inserted? Maybe you don't use utf-8 on view records.

Comment: I've done a var_dump right before they are inserted. At that point they are still correct, that means that the database is encoding them wrong. But I can't see where or why it would do it.

Thank you!

Comment: On windows, presumably on other systems too, there is a MySQL Workbench program. You can see there how the records are REALLY stored.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem was, that the tables were still using different encoding than the database. Another fix was to use: SET NAMES 'utf8' to remind MySQL that I'm using UTF-8 just in-case it forgot.